# saving content of multiple TinyMCE in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinyjs

I am using two instances of tinyMCE in shiny. I would like to save the content of both of these instances as a csv file using a single action button. I can use two action button but that defeats my goal. Not really great with javascript and how to make it work in R. I was able to source some code to save the output of first instance. Following is a working example.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <-  fluidRow(
        titlePanel("tinyMCE Shiny"),
        br(),
        column(width=6,
               tags$script(src='https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js'),
               tags$form(method="post",
                         tags$textarea(id="textHolder1"),
                         tags$textarea(id="textHolder2")
               ),
               br(),
               actionButton("fetch", "Get Results!", icon=icon("lightbulb-o"),class="btn-primary",
                            onclick = "Shiny.onInputChange('typedText', tinyMCE.get('textHolder1').getContent());"),
               tags$script("
                           tinymce.init({
                           selector:'#textHolder1',
                           theme: 'modern',
                           height: 500,
                           plugins: ['advlist autolink link image lists charmap preview hr table','wordcount',],
                           menubar: true,
                           toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | bullist | link | image ',
                           });"),
               tags$script("
                           tinymce.init({
                           selector:'#textHolder2',
                           theme: 'modern',
                           height: 500,
                           plugins: ['advlist autolink link image lists charmap preview hr table','wordcount',],
                           menubar: true,
                           toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | bullist | link | image ',
                           });")
  ),
  column(width=6,
         tags$style(HTML('pre {height:240px;}')),
         tags$label(`for`="rawText", "Raw String"),
         hr(),
         tags$pre(textOutput("rawText")),
         br(),
         tags$label(`for`="htmlText", "HTML Version"),
         hr(),
         tags$pre(htmlOutput("htmlText"))
  )
    )

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
   
    output$htmlText <- renderUI({
        req(input$typedText)
        HTML(enc2utf8(input$typedText))
    })
    
    output$rawText <- renderText({
        req(input$typedText)
        enc2utf8(input$typedText)
    })
    
    observeEvent(input$fetch,{
        j <- data.frame("t"= HTML(enc2utf8(input$typedText)))
        write.csv(j,"test.csv")
    })
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate the input from two text in  `onclick` -

```
actionButton("fetch", "Get Results!", icon=icon("lightbulb-o"),class="btn-primary",
                      onclick = "Shiny.onInputChange('typedText', tinyMCE.get('textHolder1').getContent() + tinyMCE.get('textHolder2').getContent());")
```

Complete app code -

```
ui <-  fluidRow(
  titlePanel("tinyMCE Shiny"),
  br(),
  column(width=6,
         tags$script(src='https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js'),
         tags$form(method="post",
                   tags$textarea(id="textHolder1"),
                   tags$textarea(id="textHolder2")
         ),
         br(),
         actionButton("fetch", "Get Results!", icon=icon("lightbulb-o"),class="btn-primary",
                      onclick = "Shiny.onInputChange('typedText', tinyMCE.get('textHolder1').getContent() + tinyMCE.get('textHolder2').getContent());"),
         tags$script("
                           tinymce.init({
                           selector:'#textHolder1',
                           theme: 'modern',
                           height: 500,
                           plugins: ['advlist autolink link image lists charmap preview hr table','wordcount',],
                           menubar: true,
                           toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | bullist | link | image ',
                           });"),
         tags$script("
                           tinymce.init({
                           selector:'#textHolder2',
                           theme: 'modern',
                           height: 500,
                           plugins: ['advlist autolink link image lists charmap preview hr table','wordcount',],
                           menubar: true,
                           toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | bullist | link | image ',
                           });")
  ),
  column(width=6,
         tags$style(HTML('pre {height:240px;}')),
         tags$label(`for`="rawText", "Raw String"),
         hr(),
         tags$pre(textOutput("rawText")),
         br(),
         tags$label(`for`="htmlText", "HTML Version"),
         hr(),
         tags$pre(htmlOutput("htmlText"))
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$htmlText <- renderUI({
    req(input$typedText)
    HTML(enc2utf8(input$typedText))
  })
  
  output$rawText <- renderText({
    req(input$typedText)
    enc2utf8(input$typedText)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$fetch,{
    j <- data.frame(t = HTML(enc2utf8(input$typedText)))
    write.csv(j,"test.csv")
  })
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you but this solution but it does not solve my issue. I should have been clearer in my question. If you notice i have 2 instances of TinyMCE identified using textholder1 and textholder2. I am only able to save output of textholder1 using the action button. I would like to save output of both textholder1 and textholder2 using single action button.

Comment: @AtmajitsinhGohil Got it, Can you try the updated answer?

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you...its a very good solution. I am really new to javascript.